# Is there any way to add different images per container in a listview builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Image of listview builderstrong text]

I wan't to add image by opening camera when pressed Add Images button to the corresponding container. How to achieve this?

Comment: you can either create 2 separate widgets for your output, or you can merge it to one, just hide the image displaying widget when there's no data. (use Streambuilder)

Comment: can you show me a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomeScreen());
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Model> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    list.add(Model([null,null,null]));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Track Assets'),
      ),
      //use ListView.builder for dynamic content
      body: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          itemCount: list.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (con, ind) {
            return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.grey.withAlpha(70),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(children: [
                      Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('Freezer',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            Text('Lorem Ipsum',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15))
                          ]),
                      SizedBox(width: 25),
                      Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.black),
                      Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                      Column(children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 150,
                          child: FlatButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              onPressed: () {
                                //todo
                              },
                              child: Text('Track',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 150,
                          child: FlatButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              onPressed: () {
                                //todo
                              },
                              child: Text('Relocate',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 150,
                          child: FlatButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              onPressed: () {
                                //todo
                              },
                              child: Text('Add Images',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ]),
                    Divider(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      thickness: 0.7,
                      indent: 25,
                      endIndent: 25,
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap:true,
                    scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount:list[ind].images==null?1: list[ind].images.length+1,
                    itemBuilder:(con2,ind2){
                      return list[ind].images.length==ind ?
                        FlatButton(
                            child: Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: Colors.grey),
                          onPressed:(){
                            getImage(ind);
                          }): Image.file(list[ind].images[ind2]);
                    }
                  ),
                  ],
                ));
          }),
    );
  }
  Future getImage(int listIndex) async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if(image!=null)
    setState(() {
      if(list[listIndex].images == null)
         list[listIndex].images = [];
      list[listIndex].images.add(image);
    });
  }
}

class Model {
  List<File> images;
  //or use network path
  //String path;
  //other properties

  Model(this.images);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can i add more than 3 images(like a listview.builder horizontally) using this code?

Comment: Yes ! You can add more than 3 !

Comment: the get image function has 2 arguments and calling only by one argument.

Comment: Oops sorry ! Remove the 2nd argument in function !

Comment: if removed what will be this statement =>  list[listIndex].images[imageIndex]=image;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208473/discussion-between-naveen-avidi-and-fizik-bata).